# Second order partial of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the function $f(x,y)=\dfrac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, $f=0$ otherwise.

I have to compute $\dfrac{d^2f}{dydx}(0,0)$.

I know that I have to calculate $\frac{df}{dx}$ first.
But that is ,

$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.
When I put it in wolframalpha, it gives me this calculation, and also **just** $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as an alternative form.
[wolframalpha calculation link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5Bxy%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5D%2Fdx)

Why do I just ignore the y'? I don't know what y(x) is, as a function of x. 
y and x are independent functions, no?

Comment: The equality $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is not even wrong, it's meaningless. Using your lingo, one would say that $y$ is not a function of $x$, it's simply another variable. You need to use the definition of partial derivative.

Comment: As an alternative to @GitGud's (very good) explanation, note that $y,x$ are independent variables, so that changing $x$ does not affect $y$ at all, you are free to choose them independently of one another, so the term you write as ${dy\over dx}=0$ since $y$ is a constant relative to $x$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: This is $\frac12r^2\sin4\theta$ in polar coordinates.  Does that make it easier to find the partial derivative?

Answer (score 4):

For $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ one easily computes
$$f_x(x,y)={x^4y + 4x^2y^3-y^5\over (x^2+y^2)^2}\ .$$
The point $(0,0)$ is special; therefore we have to resort to the definition of $f_x(0,0)$:
$$f_x(0,0)=\lim_{x\to0}{f(x,0)-f(0,0)\over x}=0\ .$$
It follows that
$$f_x(0,y)=\cases{-y&$(y\ne0)$\cr 0&$(y=0)$\cr}\ ,$$
whence $f_x(0,y)=-y$ for all $y$. This leads to
$${\partial^2 f \over\partial y\partial x}(0,0)=-1\ .$$
A similar computation would give
$${\partial^2 f \over\partial x\partial y}(0,0)=1\ ,$$
the reason being that these mixed derivatives both fail to be continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for jumping in this conversation so late, but how do you evaluate $f(0,0)$, like you say in the second step? Isn't this still undefined? Another answerer used $f(0,y)$. Is this the correct approach? If so, it doesn't seem to match with the definition of a partial derivative that I was given. How can I know to use $f(0,y)$?

Comment: @BlakeSplitter: The value $f(0,0)=0$ was given in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Given

$$f(x,y) = \frac{{xy({x^2} - {y^2})}}{{{x^2} + {y^2}}}$$

The graph looks like:

[image]

Got it!

For derivative with respect to x-Axis we have to consider:

$$\frac{{f(h,y) - f(0,y)}}{h} = \frac{{y\left( {{h^2} - {y^2}} \right)}}{{{h^2} + {y^2}}}$$

Then we get:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f(h,y) - f(0,y)}}{h} =  - y$$

If we instead consider derivative with respect to y-Axis, we are using:

$$\frac{{f(x,h) - f(x,0)}}{h} = \frac{{x\left( {{x^2} - {h^2}} \right)}}{{{h^2} + {x^2}}}$$

An in the limit, we get:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f(x,h) - f(x,0)}}{h} = x$$

Now the mixed partials must be different.

Comment: This isn't right. There's no reason why $\dfrac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial y\partial x}}$ should be continuous and in fact, it is not. This function is an example of why continuity is a necessary condition in [Schwarz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem). (It turns out this example is actually shown in the wikipedia link). It's easy to see from the definition that $\dfrac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial y\partial x}}(0,0) = -1$.

Comment: @Git Gud: I'm totally on your side. But task was to find $$\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial y\partial x}}(0,0)$$
It depends on direction I'm moving into the origin. And I know
Schwarz's theorem very well. At the moment, we are knowing
this mixed derivative. Did you find any errors in my calculation?

Comment: The $\partial f/\partial x$ moves towards the $y$-axis.  Then you set $x=0$.  Then the $\partial f/\partial y$ moves vertically to zero.

Comment: @Frieder The equality $ \lim \limits_{h \to 0} F(h,h) = 0$ is correct, but the conclusion $\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial y\partial x}}(0,0) = 0$ isn't.

Comment: @Git Gud and Michael: Did an edit. Thank's. This naturally
agrees with Schwaz's theorem.

Comment: @Michael *This comment is directed at Frieder, I'm just pinging Michael because the ping system will not ping Michael as Frieder intended in the comment above.* I hadn't read your answer completely and I still haven't, I merely noticed that you were saying that because $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} F(h,h) = 0$ (by the way, check the mathjax code for this formula, it's simpler than what you used), one would have $\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial y\partial x}}(0,0) = 0$ which isn't true. This  is still written in your answer and shouldn't be. It's better to clean up and leave only correct content.

Comment: @GitGud: No problem. See it the same way! Thank's a lot.