# Give an example of a continuous function z = f(x,y) over the plane such that at (0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Give an example of a continuous function z = f(x,y) over the plane such that at (0,0)

$$
\frac{\partial^{2} z}{\partial x\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial^{2} z}{\partial y\partial x} $$

Past exam question that I'm having trouble understanding. Any hints would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).

Comment: [Second order partial of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193120/second-order-partial-of-fx-y-fracxyx2-y2x2y2)