# Showing that $f_{xy}(0,0) \neq f_{yx}(0,0)$ for $xy \cdot \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: analysis, functions, partial-derivative

Let the function $\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$f(x,y) := \begin{cases}xy \cdot \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}, \text{ if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 0, \text{ else }\end{cases}$

Calculating $f_{xy}(x,y)$ and $f_{yx}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ gives

$$f_x(x,y) = \dfrac{y\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{2yx^2}{x^2+y^2}-\dfrac{2yx^2\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$

$$f_y(x,y) = -\dfrac{2xy^2}{y^2+x^2}+\dfrac{x\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{y^2+x^2}-\dfrac{2xy^2\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{\left(y^2+x^2\right)^2}$$

$$f_{xy}(x,y) = -\dfrac{2y^2}{y^2+x^2}+\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{y^2+x^2}+\dfrac{2x^2}{y^2+x^2}-\dfrac{2y^2\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{\left(y^2+x^2\right)^2}-\dfrac{2x^2\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{\left(y^2+x^2\right)^2}+\dfrac{8x^2y^2\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{\left(y^2+x^2\right)^3} $$

$$f_{yx}(x,y) = \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}-\dfrac{2y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\dfrac{2x^2\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}-\dfrac{2y^2\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}+\dfrac{8y^2x^2\left(x^2-y^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^3}$$

How can one show that $f_{xy}(0,0) \neq f_{yx}(0,0)?$

If I put the values in the functions the denominators would be $0$ and that is undefined.

Comment: Try to use proper defination of partial deivative.

Comment: $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}=0$$
thus $f_y(0,0)=0$ like this

Comment: It is an example in [this wikipedia's page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Requirement_of_continuity)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Second order partial of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193120/second-order-partial-of-fx-y-fracxyx2-y2x2y2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_{xy}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f_y(h,0)-f_y(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\lim_{k\to0}\dfrac{f(h,k)-f(h,0)}{k}-\lim_{k\to0}\dfrac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}{k}}{h}$$

This gives $$f_{xy}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\lim_{k\to0}\dfrac{hk\frac{h^2-k^2}{h^2+k^2}-0}{k}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{h}=1$$

Similarly 
$$f_{yx}=\lim_{k\to0}\dfrac{f_x(0,k)-f_x(0,0)}{k} = \lim_{k\to0}\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h,k)-f(0,k)}{h}-\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}}{k}$$
This gives
$$f_{xy}=\lim_{k\to0}\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{hk\frac{h^2-k^2}{h^2+k^2}-0}{h}-0}{k}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{-k}{k}=-1$$